# How to get correct rowEntity in Angular UI grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm currently working on the Angular UI grid. The edit functionality is implemented and it works fine except one case when I push or remove any row to/from a grid at first after that I receive an incorrect rowEntity object during row editing. I believe it is easy to get a reason of "issue" who has valuable experience.

Let's say a grid contains two rows initially. Then I add a row to the top with: `$scope.gridOptions.data.unshift(//here is an object);`

Thus, there are already 3 rows in the grid. If I try to edit the third row, I'll get an rowEntity object with data from the current second row instead of the third.

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

  $scope.gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, function (rowEntity) {
    //the rowEntity object is incorrect here if any row was either added or removed before the row that is under edit action now
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I misunderstand or don't know? I could resolve it if it would be possible to pass a rendered index row in on.saveRow().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloaded DOM of the grid to get correct sequence of rowEntities.